# Rails Paperclip Gem - save parent model ID to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a model of **ThreesixtyViewer** which also has a nested resource of the **ThreesixtyViewerImage** model. An image attribute is being saved via the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) - but I am having issues updating the file path how it's needed.

The images for each **ThreesixtyViewer** needs to be saved together within one directory that is associated with the specific viewer. For example:

```
/public/system/threesixty_viewer_images/12/large/filename.jpg
```

In this example, the **12** in the path would be the id of the specific threesixtyviewer - but I cannot find any examples with that functionality. If the **ThreesixtyViewer** had an ID of 57, then the path would look like so:

```
/public/system/threesixty_viewer_images/57/large/filename.jpg
```

**threesixty_viewer.rb**

```
belongs_to :article

has_many :threesixty_viewer_images, dependent: :delete_all
accepts_nested_attributes_for :threesixty_viewer_images, allow_destroy: true
```

**threesixty_viewer_image.rb**

```
belongs_to :threesixty_viewer

has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "500x500#", large: "1440x800>" },
  path: ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:VIEWER_ID/:size/:filename',
  url: '/system/:class/:VIEWER_ID/:size/:filename'
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I know the :path and :url attributes need to beupdated for the has_attached_file within the **threesixty_viewer_image.rb** - but I am unsure as to how I can get the id for the threesixty_viewer... for now I added a :VIEWER_ID in it's place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for anyone who can lend an eye!

Answer (score 2):

You can add any of the models attributes to that path for this object. I believe you can even go so far as adding anything that the method will respond to, so you can even create path helpers for returning specific strings (such as month it was saved, year, etc).

In your case,  **ThreesixtyViewerImage** is a child model, your table should include a column for the parent model. In your case, that attribute is probably **:threesixty_viewer_id**

Here is what I think you need for setting that path on **threesixty_viewer_image.rb**:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  styles: { small: "500x500#", large: "1440x800>" },
  path: ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:threesixty_viwer_id/:size/:filename",
  url: "/system/:class/:threesixty_viewer_id/:size/:filename"

validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**EDIT**

Everything I said above is dead wrong. *My apologies!* What you need to use is a `Paperclip::Interpolation`. [Here's a link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations)

Here's what I did to make use:

1. Create a new file: `config/initializers/paperclip_interpolators`
2. Place something like this in that file:

   ```
   Paperclip.interpolates :threesixty_viewer_id do |attachment, style|
     attachment.instance.threesixty_viewer_id
   end
   ```
3. Restart your application
4. Regenerate your paths/folders for the attachments. [Here's a Link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#generatingregenerating-your-thumbnails)

Anytime you want another attribute in your path, just add another interpolator! Sorry again for misleading you before.

Comment: When I do this with **:threesixty_viewer_id** or any other attribute that should be available (ie :article_id) - it saves the directory as exactly that... so it now looks like `/public/system/threesixty_viewer_images/:threesixty_viewer_id/large/filename.jpg`

Comment: updated my answer with some more specific details about interpolations and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`@colin_hagan` is on the right path - I would suggest you look into [Paperclip Interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations):

```
#app/models/threesixty_viewer_image.rb
class ThreesixtyViewerImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :threesixty_viewer

   has_attached_file :image,
      path: ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:threesixty_viewer_id/:size/:filename",
      url: "/system/:class/:threesixty_viewer_id/:size/:filename"

   Paperclip.interpolates :threesixty_viewer_id do |attachment, style|
      attachment.instance.threesixty_viewer_id
   end
end
```

Notice the double quotes, rather than single.

Double quotes should be used for interpolation - single quotes are for literal strings (*I think*).

---

Another thing I found some time back is the [`paperclip_defaults`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) option -- allowing you to specify `styles` etc for any attachments:

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.paperclip_defaults = { 
   styles: { small: "500x500#", large: "1440x800>" }
}
```

These can be overridden in your respective models - it's just handy for me, as it means you don't have to explicitly define `styles` each time you have an attachment.

Comment: this took care of it thanks! the paperclip_defaults is a great tip too, will definitely plan on using that on my next project! Thanks again!